# Pixellated Gradients when exporting PDF from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf, gradient, gradient-mesh

I designed a business card with some graphics that have gradients, but every time I export a PDF the gradients show up pixellated. I tried setting Print > Advanced > Transparency and Overprint > High Quality but that did not work. Does anyone know how I can export a PDF for print that has smooth gradients? I would appreciate any ideas you have.

Here's what it looks like in Illustrator.
[image: Illustrator screencap]

And here's what it looks like in the PDF.
[image: PDF screencap]

Comment: What zoom percentage are you looking at the PDF? **All** gradients in  will be "pixelated" if you zoom in.

Comment: Can you attach the file?

Comment: I have had this concern before with small sizes. You "fit to screen" and see the artwork in a much larger scale than you would with a poster and everything looks pixelated. It is probably fine. I think that a gradient mesh needs to be rasterized in a pdf, and you have used "High Quality" = 300 ppi. You could try adding a 300 ppi image next to the graphics and compare the pixel size in the pdf.

Comment: Take a look at the **compression** settings in **Save Adobe Pdf** dialog.

Comment: Thanks Scott and Wolff, I think my issue was just that I was zooming in too far. If I zoom out, it looks okay.

Answer (score 2):

1. go to  **Effects/ Document raster effects settings ...**
2. change your resolution to 300 (even more if you want better quality)

The reason for this is that mesh gradients are not rendered inside a PDF (or web browsers ) so they get rasterized before exporting